# Undermoderated parts of Stack Exchange: mallet, topic-modeling

Tags: discussion, support, flags

I have raised some flags on the tags [mallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mallet) and [topic-modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topic-modeling). Essentially, the questions weren't about programming, but about the application and interpretation of the underlying statistical methods.

However, the flags just aged away and no moderator was available to deal with them.

The questions remain unanswered.

I think this frustrates users coming along here. Off-topic questions need to be weeded out: To show the OP that he is looking for an answer at the wrong place, and not to wast the time of the casual passer-by (coming from a search engine and having the same question).

Comment: What flags did you raise? Most flags aren't handled by moderators

Comment: I raised the flag "off-topic".

Comment: Yah, thats handled by the close votes review queue. The one that 3k+ users can review. Unpopular tags often suffer aging flags there, since the queue is massively backed up at the moment (6.5k+ review tasks)

Comment: Life on the long tail of SO is not that easy, questions can never gather enough votes to ever get closed or deleted.  Most significant problem I see is a general disinterest in the tags, only *one* of the [mallet] questions right now has a negative score.  If nobody DVs poor content then automatic cleanup can't work either.  This is something you can do, you'll be disappointed if you expect somebody else to take care of it.

Comment: @HansPassant: I looked it up: I have already used my downvote on the flagged questions except one (I usually didn't downvote users with only 1 poitn of reputation, but maybe I should rethink this).

Comment: @jknappen: if you feel you can educate them and have them clean-up their question, then commenting is the good answer; if the question is not salvageable however, do downvote (and you might want to comment too). Downvoting questions is free (you do not lose reputation) and the user's reputation will not go below 1 anyway. Also, they can recoup their reputation by deleting their question themselves which will clean-up!

Comment: @jknappen You can hop into the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and post a close vote review request.  That can help to get some more eyeballs on low traffic post.

Comment: @jknappen had same problem in jasper-reports tag (everything aged away), find a duplicate and convince OP or use SOCVR.